# JQuery Unable to get property 'json' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

Im building a windows 8 app (html) 
And have a api im fetching data from.
I keep getting this error however

- 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'json' of undefined or null reference

in my scripts1.js file. then my program crashes -_-.

Here is the the code i use

```
 $(function () {
    startRefresh();
});

function startRefresh() {
    setTimeout(startRefresh, 10000);
    var url = 'http://pubapi.cryptsy.com/api.php?method=singlemarketdata&marketid=132';
    $.getJSON('http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20json%20where%20url%3D%22' + encodeURIComponent(url) + '%22&format=json', function (data) {
        jQuery('#ticker').html(data['query'].results.json.return.markets.DOGE.lasttradeprice);
        jQuery('#ticker').append(' ' + data['query'].results.json.return.markets.DOGE.secondarycode);
        jQuery('#ticker2').html(data['query'].results.json.return.markets.DOGE.lasttradetime);
        jQuery('#ticker3').html(data['query'].results.json.return.markets.DOGE.volume);

    });
}
```

This is located in scripts1.js Then i use   ect.
It works everything comes and displays just get that error. Not sure what to do.

Comment: ...and what does your returned JSON look like (if it gets returned at all)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like data['query'].results is undefined. Pasting the JSON you get will help.

Also, one small piece of advice: If you are going to access an in-depth attribute and, specially, a DOM node several times, you might want to recycle a reference to it rather than travelling again and again to fetch it for performance reasons. Something like this:

```
var ticker = jQuery('#ticker');
var DOGE = data['query'].results.json.return.markets.DOGE;
ticker.html(DOGE.lasttradeprice);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like, occasionally, the API will send back some JSON that, when parsed, doesn't contain a results object. To mitigate this you should put a condition in to catch this eventuality.

```
if (data.query.results) {
  jQuery('#ticker').html(data['query'].results.json.return.markets.DOGE.lasttradeprice);
  // rest of DOM update code
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/99YaV/).